# Elevator Simulator in Python

Tags: python

I need help with an elevator simulator in Python and I don't have much experience.  There should be a user entered amount of customers that have randomized start and destination floors. Right now I'm just coding the simple strategy of the elevator going all the way to the top, and then back to the bottom. When I run my code, the program infinitely loops. I can't figure out why.  Also, I'm not sure how to code my building's output method, which I want to display which customers had which floors and how many floors the elevator visited. Thanks for your help.

```
import random

class Elevator(object):
    def __init__(self, num_of_floors, register_list, direction = "up", cur_floor=1):
        self.total_floors = num_of_floors
        self.reg_list = register_list
        self.floor = cur_floor
        self.direct = direction
    def move(self):
        """Moves the elevator one floor"""
        if self.total_floors == self.floor:
            self.direct = "down"
        if self.direct == "up":
            self.floor += 1
        else:
            self.floor -= 1
    def register_customer(self, customer):
        self.reg_list.append(customer)
    def cancel_customer(self, customer):
        self.reg_list.remove(customer)

class Building(object):
    def __init__(self, num_of_floors, customer_list, elevator):
        self.total_floors = num_of_floors
        self.customers = customer_list
    def run(self):
        while elevator.floor != 0:
            for customer in self.customers:
                if elevator.floor == customer.on_floor:
                    elevator.reg_list.append(customer)
                    customer.indicator = 1
                elif elevator.floor == customer.going_floor:
                    elevator.reg_list.remove(customer)
                    customer.indicator = 0
                    customer.fin = 1
            elevator.move()
                
    def output(self):
        pass

class Customer(object):
    def __init__(self, ID, num_of_floors, cur_floor=0, dst_floor=0, in_elevator=0, finished=0):
        self.ident = ID
        self.indicator = in_elevator
        self.fin = finished
        cur_floor = random.randint(1, num_of_floors)
        self.on_floor = cur_floor
        dst_floor = random.randint(1, num_of_floors)
        while dst_floor == cur_floor:
            dst_floor = random.randint(1, num_of_floors)
        self.going_floor = dst_floor
    

customer_count = int(input("How many customers are in the building?: "))
floor_count = int(input("How many floors does the building have?: "))
cus_list = []
for i in range(1, customer_count+1):
    cus_list.append(Customer(i, floor_count))
elevator = Elevator(floor_count, cus_list)
building = Building(floor_count, cus_list, elevator)
```

Comment: Wouldn't want to ride in that elevator :P Check your while loop in building it looks funny... try outputting the elevator.floor variable to console in your loop.

Comment: That `while` loop looks fine to me - it's saying the customer is going to want to go to a floor other than the one he/she is on.

Comment: ya sorry edited that.

Comment: As long as num_of_floors is large enough ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
def run(self):
    while elevator.floor != 0:
        print(elevator.floor)
        for customer in self.customers:
            print(customer)
            if elevator.floor == customer.on_floor:
                elevator.reg_list.append(customer)
                customer.indicator = 1
            elif elevator.floor == customer.going_floor:
                elevator.reg_list.remove(customer)
                customer.indicator = 0
                customer.fin = 1
        elevator.move()
```

When you do elevator.reg_list.append(customer), you are re-appending the customer to the list, increasing it size (self.customers is also a reference to this same list) so the "for customer in self.customers" loops forever.

Lets follow "cus_list" :

```
elevator = Elevator(floor_count, cus_list)
building = Building(floor_count, cus_list, elevator)

class Building(object):
    def __init__(self, num_of_floors, customer_list, elevator):
        self.total_floors = num_of_floors
        self.customers = customer_list

class Elevator(object):
    def __init__(self, num_of_floors, register_list, direction = "up", cur_floor=1):
        self.total_floors = num_of_floors
        self.reg_list = register_list # <-------- THIS IS "cus_list" reference
```

Finally in class Building:

```
 elevator.reg_list.append(customer)
```

elevator is a global variable here created outside the scope of the class FYI.

**A fix may be as follows**

The elevator starts out empty right?

```
class Elevator(object):
    def __init__(self, num_of_floors, register_list, direction = "up", cur_floor=1):
        self.total_floors = num_of_floors
        self.reg_list = []
```

Comment: No, they are two different references to the same list. OP should probably use `self.reg_list = []` in the Elevator so that the Elevator doesn't start out full

Comment: yes a reference to the same list as I said above in my answer. Sorry its long :S

Comment: how would i go about actually displaying what the elevator does?  For example, displaying "Elevator picks up Customer 1 on floor 1...Elevator moves to floor two and picks up Customer 3....Elevator moves to floor 3, drops off Customer 1 and picks up Customer 4...etc etc"

Comment: use print statements. EG: print("Elevator picks up Customer " + customer + " on floor " + elevator.floor) this is python 3 syntax. Python 2 omit the "("s